# Looking for feedback from the community regarding "Dislikes"

Tags: support, voting

I want an answer from a guy who knows the community best. ;) Why are people keep disliking my posts when they have good grammar?

I mean there is no sense to dislike it. It can be only I didn't put a period at the end of a sentence.

Just want to know, because I don't want to keep losing my reputation.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the question that is in dispute? In particular, the "guy who know there community best"?

Comment: I mean the guy who is there long time, so he know how the community should react :)

Comment: If your question here is an example of your typical questions, your grammar could use a bit of work which might help.

Comment: It's really important to know that **downvotes aren't dislikes**. While on meta they are often used to express one's opinion, on the main site they are a moderation tool to separate good from bad content. 
Some posts about up and downvoting: [Please don't misuse the voting system](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/please-dont-misuse-the-voting-system), [Reasons to downvote](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10473/why-should-1-reputation-be-deducted-from-downvoting/10475#10475)

Comment: I too, would like to know why people downvote my detailed, well-researched posts without comments. But you gotta know that the Internet is not a kind place, especially on the Stackexchange network. Don't let downvotes discourage you from making good posts.

Comment: @Yuu Again, *down votes are not personal*. It has nothing to do with kindness, or hostility.

Comment: @Frank No worries about that, I didn't take offense. It'd be nice if the downvote came with a comment on what the question/answer is lacking though, since we'd all like to improve.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off: while your grammar could use some improvement, it's not that bad, and it usually isn't the main reason.

[Why isn't this mob farm working?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294062/why-isnt-this-mob-farm-working) is a Minecraft question. Some users have a tendency to downvote Minecraft questions that they think aren't well researched because we get A LOT of them, and not always of decent quality. In addition, it was your first question, and as such you made a lot of the common starter mistakes: not editing your question with new information, posting extra details in comments and answers and a vague "it's not working" core question.

[Can you write a review for a game you don't own?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/293909/can-you-write-a-review-for-a-game-you-dont-own/294074#294074) is an answer that doesn't really add anything to the topic. the only thing that's relevant to the discussion has already been answered in another answer, and the original question didn't wonder about the trading cards, so those are off-topic.

[Clash Of Clans Android Problem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294117/clash-of-clans-android-problem/294133#294133) has by far the poorest grammar, which is probably part of the reason why it's downvoted. The other reason is that it promotes account sharing and breaking terms of service, something that we in general do not approve of.

[Two Pokemon with same CP, one is wonder one is not](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294153/two-pokemon-with-same-cp-one-is-wonder-one-is-not/294157#294157) doesn't answer the question at all. The question is about 2 pokemon that have already been appraised, and you're talking about appraisal to figure out which one to use.

In general, Arqade and the Stack Exchange network is a pretty hostile place to first time users that are mostly unaware of our no-nonsense approach. There aren't many sites that work like we do, and that may put off first time users who aren't used to our way of working.

My suggestion to you is that you should first take a look around at the top voted questions and answers. Look at how we do things, try and interpret what we like and don't like, and from that make a decision on whether you think you can adapt your questions and answers to these preferences in the future.